Ubuntu 24.10 kernel 6.11.0.9 IPU6 camera not working
I have a Dell Latitude 7450. My camera was not working when installed Ubuntu 24.10, and it didn't after the upgrade either. I then used ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6, but even now I get the below error.
Nov 07 09:57:02 kernel: intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Direct firmware load for intel/ipu6epmtl_fw.bin failed with error -2
Nov 07 09:57:02 kernel: intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Direct firmware load for intel/ipu/ipu6epmtl_fw.bin failed with error -2
Nov 07 09:57:02 kernel: intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Requesting signed firmware failed
Nov 07 09:57:02 kernel: intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: probe with driver intel-ipu6 failed with error -2

